# What are all the nuances and uses of 至る? (に至って) (に至っては) (に至っても) (に至る)

Tags: grammar, nuances

I'm studying for the N1.  And there are several not so often used structures that you really need to know the minute differences between.  One of these is the uses of 至る.  As far as I know, these are the structures that I am familiar with:

- に至って - once it reached the very point of X, at this extreme X
- に至っても - even up to this very point of X
- に至っては - given this extreme example, this is the situation
- に至る - all the way to X, leading to X, more emphatic than まで?
- に至るまで　- as far as X, up until X

Am I missing any other uses or nuances?

This seems like the kind of question that should have been asked before, but I couldn't find it any searches. Sorry if this is a repeat.

Comment: `...there are several not so often used[sic] structures...`  Several?  Like ***every*** grammar pattern in N1 is a hardly-ever-used pattern.</semi sarcasm>

Comment: It sounds like you understand 至る (basically reach/arrive at some point, possibly in an abstract sense) but the challenge is the differences between the so called "basics":〜て〜；〜ても〜；〜ては〜；〜まで〜 etc.

Comment: @Tim Yeah, that might be so.  I can't quickly decide between which to use for some reason.  The use of the 'basics' at this higher level seems to trip me up more than it should.  But then again, there are particle questions on the N1 all the time, so I guess I'm not the only one.

Comment: If you add the example/question you struggle with to your question somebody might be able to explain. At the moment your question is a bit broad.

Comment: I agree that the question is too broad, i.e. is about more than being about 至る. You could just as well ask the same question using する as the verb here.

Answer (score 2):

An important one to know is “至らない○○○”, where there is no stated object (i.e., [object]に至らない) to where that something has not reached. In this case, what has not been reached is *high competence* or *perfection*.

> - **至らない**点がありましたら、ご指摘ください。
>     *If there is anything unsatisfactory, please point them out.*
> - 私の**至らなさ**が招いた結果です。
>     *This is the result of my incompetence. (There is only my incompetence to blame.)*
> - 私の**至らない**英語でちゃんと伝わりましたか？
>     *Did you understand my imperfect English?*

And then a pretty common idiom 至れり尽くせり, which is used to describe excellent, pampering service:

> [至れり尽くせり](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%87%B3%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8A%E5%B0%BD%E3%81%8F%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8A)の航海経験
>   *a very pampering cruise experience*

Answer (score 1):

In these cases a kokugo dictionary really helps. If you're studying for N1, sites like Kotobank will be one of your greatest sources of information:
[Definition of 至る on kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%87%B3%E3%82%8B-433135#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89)